# Not recognized as an internal or external command for node js modules

Tags: npm

How to fix not recognized as an internal or external command after installing node modules.

For Example: npm install -g grunt-cli bower yo

After installation while typing yo or bower. Its throwing error "Moule_name" not recognized as an internal or external command

Answer (score 1):

Got it!!!

Issue is with environment variables. Mentioned node modules will not be accessed globally. So the app data path should be updated in system variables(Environment variable).

path:  ;C:\Users\currentusername\AppData\Roaming\npm;

Answer (score 0):

A similar issue has been resolved here: [Making Global NPM packages available to all users on windows 2012 server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38570209/making-global-npm-packages-available-to-all-users-on-windows-2012-server)

It is a path issue, which can happen in Windows if you use a different account to install the global modules (i.e. if you use a separate Administrator account with elevated privileges, like in many corporate environments).