# Making Global NPM packages available to all users on windows 2012 server

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install

I am trying to install continues integration server. This server will pull data from GIT and it will try to build the application. Since I am using windows 2012 server, multiple users can trigger the build. For this purpose, I want to ensure all the node packages I install as admin are available to all users.

How can I:

1. **Install node packages globally that are available to all users.**
2. I want to use a locally hosted node registry. I don't want to use node registry.
3. After the installing the packages, how can I validate if all users can access the packages?

Comment: Great question. Even in 2022, got stuck with this!
I am setting up a self hosted Azure Pipeline Agent, and wanted couple of npm packages pre-installed so that the DevOPs pipeline tasks can make use of it. 

Ran into this problem :) Thank you for asking.

Answer (score 64):

Had the same issue. Needed the CI build agent to run a global package on the CLI. Saw [this post](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/4534#issuecomment-226904124) in a new feature request for system-wide `npm -g` for Windows.

In short:

1. Open an administrator level command prompt
2. Note the current global prefix: `npm prefix -g`
3. Set the global prefix to the CI user: `npm config set prefix <C:\Users\CI_USER\AppData\Roaming\npm>`
4. Install the needed packages: `npm i -g PKG`
5. Restore the prefix to the previous value.

Comment: What if my CI build agent is running under 'Network Service' user name? Where should I set the prefix?

Comment: +1 I would gladly give your brain a hug. :) Solved the issue big time, plus it added to my knowledge something I did not know about.

Comment: I like how my top two answers are both about setting up a dev environment (npm, Qt) rather than any programming issue.

Comment: +1 great info on changing global "prefix" setting. FWIW, I was able to install Gulp CLI for all users by setting the prefix (`npm config set prefix`) to the NodeJS system-wide install directory, and then running `npm install -g gulp-cli`. Maybe it's a little hacky, but the only way I found to provide a truly "global" install on Windows.

Comment: For system-wide access don't forget to add the directory to the system path. On most Windows versions (including Server 2012) you need to press Windows+Pause --> click Advanced system settings --> Environment Variables --> System Variables --> Path --> Edit, then add the new folder to the end. Click OK --> OK --> Apply, THEN open any command prompt and issue a `refreshenv` command, followed by `pm2` and it should run.

Comment: You actually can do this `npm config set prefix <global path>` where `<global path>` --as stated by [one of the active contributors of npm](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/4534#issuecomment-226904124)-- is free from any user context to make the process user independant. I personally prefer it this way in cas where the `CI_USER` gets deleted.

Answer (score 25):

For the 'Network Service' account use the folder:

```
C:\Windows\ServiceProfiles\NetworkService\AppData\Roaming\npm
```

Comment: Just wondering if there's a system variable for this location? (like %appdata%?)

Comment: You can also run `C:\Windows\ServiceProfiles\NetworkService\AppData\Roaming\npm\npm install -g yarn` to not having to specify the prefix.

Comment: For other users to access packages through command line, add `C:\Windows\ServiceProfiles\NetworkService\AppData\Roaming\npm` to PATH in System variables.

Comment: How do you install the packages in this location? (C:\Windows\ServiceProfiles\NetworkService\AppData\Roaming...) @Augustas

Comment: For me it was default install location.

Answer (score 1):

You can add a global  environment variable `NODE_PATH` to set the package require search path. You may see here for more.
https://gist.github.com/branneman/8048520#4-the-environment

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, I need gulp to be global for all users, and for teamcity that is running under localsystem.

This is my solution: (from a fresh new setup, right after installing node)
on an "admin" command prompt

1. npm install --global gulp-cli
2. where gulp (response is: C:\Users\MYUSER\AppData\Roaming\npm\gulp)
3. open exlorer, go in that folder, and move all (gulp, gulp.cmd, node_modules that contains gulp-cli) to "C:\Program Files\nodejs"

And it works, now, gulp is global to all users, like npm.