# npm config set prefix: "the syntax of the command is incorrect"

Tags: node.js, npm

I need to install @angular/cli on the build server so it's available to all build processes which may need to call it via PowerShell cmd.  I was following the instructions on this SO page:

[Making Global NPM packages available to all users on windows 2012 server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38570209/making-global-npm-packages-available-to-all-users-on-windows-2012-server)

I was able to set the prefix once but I made a typo.  So now I'm trying to set an updated prefix but now the following cmd returns the error "The syntax of the command is incorrect":

```
npm config set prefix <C:\Users\ME\AppData\Roaming\npm>
```

Any idea why I might be getting this error?

Answer (score 0):

Try using `""` instead of `<>`